# How to use block matrices to calculate multiplication of two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

which are a $4 \times 4$ matrix and a $4 \times 2$ matrix, respectively. I can realize both of the matrices as consisting of $2 \times 2$ blocks, but I do not know how to multiply them together to obtain the resultant vector, which would be a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

I would appreciate this example be solved, so I can translate the approach of this question to other ones.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and put all necessary information in the body of the question rather than in links. Also, please make your title more specific to the question you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
A = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right] = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}\end{bmatrix}, \quad B = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1\\ \hline 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] = \begin{bmatrix}B_1\\B_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We can compute the product $AB$ as
$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} B_1 + A_{12}B_2\\ A_{21}B_1 + A_{22} B_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We can simplify this a bit by noting that $A_{11} = A_{22} = I$, $A_{21} = 0$, and $B_2 = I$. With that, we can rewrite
$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}B_1 + A_{12}\\ I\end{bmatrix}.
$$